# Initial state of redux is showing empty ( undefined )

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, redux

I am trying to get the posts when my home page loads, but when I run the app the initial state shows as empty in redux store, which should not be the case, but when I run the same code by making some other changes ( Not any change in the code of the redux data store ) then it shows the store having posts.

Below are the screen shots of all the files included.

postReducer.js

```
import { ActionTypes } from "../constants/action-types";
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
};

const postReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.SET_POSTS:
      return { ...state, posts: payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default postReducer;
```

store.js

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore } from "redux";
import reducers from "./reducers/index";

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {},
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;
```

home.js

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")

      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error : ", err);
      });

    dispatch(setPosts(response.data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```

postAction.js

```
import { ActionTypes } from "../constants/action-types";

const postReducer = (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.SET_POSTS:
      console.log("Here");
      return { ...state, posts: payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default postReducer;
```

Post.js

```
import {
  Avatar,
  Card,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  CardHeader,
  CardMedia,
  Checkbox,
  IconButton,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
// import { ExpandMore } from "@mui/icons-material";

import ShareIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Share";
import MoreVertIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVert";
import Favorite from "@mui/icons-material/Favorite";
import { FavoriteBorder } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Post = () => {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.allPosts.posts);

  console.log(posts);

  const renderList = posts.map((post, key) => {
    return (
      <Card sx={{ marginBottom: "10px" }} key={key}>
        <CardHeader
          avatar={
            <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: "red" }} aria-label="recipe">
              R
            </Avatar>
          }
          action={
            <IconButton aria-label="settings">
              <MoreVertIcon />
            </IconButton>
          }
          title="John"
          subheader={post.updatedAt}
        />
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          height="20%"
          image={post.image}
          alt="Paella dish"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            {post.description}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing>
          <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
            <Checkbox
              icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
              checkedIcon={<Favorite sx={{ color: "red" }} />}
            />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton aria-label="share">
            <ShareIcon />
          </IconButton>
          {/*  <ExpandMore
      expand={expanded}
      aria-expanded={expanded}
      aria-label="show more"
    >
      <ExpandMoreIcon />
    </ExpandMore> */}
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    );
  });

  return <>{renderList}</>;
};

export default Post;
```

postAction.js

```
import { ActionTypes } from "../constants/action-types";

export const setPosts = (posts) => {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.SET_POSTS,
    payload: posts,
  };
};
export const selectedPost = (post) => {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.SELECTED_POST,
    payload: post,
  };
};
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../src/redux/store";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: I don't see your reducer file anywhere. Also add the code in the question instead of screenshots.

Comment: If your initial state is empty is ok at first time shows you empty. When page loads looks getting a list of posts but this occurs into an async request triggered by useEffect so you never get posts instantly because it will be received in the future. If you are facing troubles about undefined properties you need ensure only run map if some value exists otherwise shows nothing or a loading while data is fetching

Comment: Hi Mr Khan, I have updated the question, please check and help. I am stuck at this.

Comment: Hi Aloiso Juinor, I tried and ran map function for only when the post is not undefined, but for the first time it never loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to check that if my post is empty before mapping it then it worked fine.

```
 const posts = useSelector((state) => state.allPosts.posts);

  console.log(posts);

  let renderList = "";

  renderList =
    posts.length > 0 ? (
      posts.map((post, key) => (
        <Card sx={{ marginBottom: "10px" }} key={key}>
          <CardHeader
            avatar={
              <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: "red" }} aria-label="recipe">
                R
              </Avatar>
            }
            action={
              <IconButton aria-label="settings">
                <MoreVertIcon />
              </IconButton>
            }
            title="John"
            subheader={post.updatedAt}
          />
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            height="20%"
            image="/images/01.jpg"
            alt="Paella dish"
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
              {post.desc}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <Checkbox
                icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
                checkedIcon={<Favorite sx={{ color: "red" }} />}
              />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="share">
              <ShareIcon />
            </IconButton>
            {/*  <ExpandMore
            expand={expanded}
            aria-expanded={expanded}
            aria-label="show more"
          >
            <ExpandMoreIcon />
          </ExpandMore> */}
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      ))
    ) : (
      <Card sx={{ marginBottom: "10px" }}> Error </Card>
    );
```